# com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: No WS-Security header found

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap, jax-ws

I study on a web service client which consumes a web service on a `remote server over SSL`.
   First of all,I'm new in web services,I created basic web services before which works on localhost.Such a complex business,I need help

`WSDL file,KeyStore file` and `TrustStore file` were given to me.I work with a computer which can access web service endpoint
    Which I have done for this web service creation;

- I generated java classes with `wsimport tool` from `wsdl file`
- Then I created a `Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse` and import these java classes
- I copy `keystore,truststore and wsdl files` in a directory of project
- In a class' main method I write the code below.

  I get below exception during runtime in the code line which  calls web service method

  ```
  com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: No WS-     Security header found exception
  ```

  The code I try to access web service below:

***Code***

```
        My_Service service=new My_Service();
        MyServicePort servicePort=service.getServicePort();

        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)servicePort;

        // In case of 1-Way SSL, only the Truststore is necessary
        TrustManagerFactory tmf= TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init((KeyStore)null);
        TrustManager[] trustMgr= tmf.getTrustManagers();
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream truststoreFile = new FileInputStream("truststore.jks");
        trustStore.load(truststoreFile, "truststore_password".toCharArray());
        truststoreFile.close();
        tmf.init(trustStore);

        // In case of 2-Way SSL, keystore and  truststore are necessary
        KeyManagerFactory kmf= KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init((KeyStore)null,null);
        KeyManager[] keyMgr = kmf.getKeyManagers();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream keystoreFile = new FileInputStream("keystore.jks");
        keyStore.load(keystoreFile, "keystore_password".toCharArray()); 
                keystoreFile.close();
        kmf.init(keyStore, "keystore_password".toCharArray());

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");//"SSLv3"
        context.init(keyMgr, trustMgr, null);
        //context.getSocketFactory();
        bp.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, context.getSocketFactory());
        bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,"username");
        bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,"password");
                bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://xxxxxxx....");

**ERROR IN THIS LINE** //List<MyEntity> list= servicePort.getEntityList();
        for(MyEntity e:list){
            System.out.println(e.getName());
        }
```

How to solve the problem?Also,any recommendations with creating such a web service client would appreciated.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Did u configur/enable your sever with https and did u add keystore path to sever?

Comment: I run this code in eclipse in a web app project i set keystore path in the code

Comment: I think u r just implementing only client side codes. There might be a sever where u can configure and deploy yours web services applications and need to configure the sever to enable https requests.